# Читать данные с stderr subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

```py
def record():
    command = 'ffmpeg -loglevel warning -hide_banner -y -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i desktop output.mkv'
    command = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    sleep(5)
    command.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
    command.stdin.flush()
    command.wait()
```

У меня есть вот такая простенькая функция.
Она запускает команду, которая записывает экран, спит 5 секунд и останавливает команду.
В конце генерируется файл `output.mkv`. В этот файл `ffmpeg` кладёт видео с записью экрана.
Если я заменю `output.mkv`, на `output.img`, то `ffmpeg` выдаст ошибку: 'Неверный формат выходного файла'
**Как я могу читать `stderr`, чтобы поймать эту ошибку, если она, конечно же, есть?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ваш код достаточно добавить две фичи:

1. При создании процесса задать параметр `stderr` конструктора `Popen` равным `subprocess.PIPE`,
2. И в отдельном потоке читать созданный файловый объект. Если ничего не прочитается, значит, ошибки не было.

Если что-то прочитается, то либо сразу выставить флаг ошибки, либо попробовать проанализировать прочитанное.

Простейший вариант может выглядеть вот так:

```py
import subprocess
import threading

failed = False


def read_stderr(stderr_pipe):
    "Sets global variable `failed` if stderr is not empty"
    global failed
    while True:
        try:
            smth = stderr_pipe.read(1)
            # Use readline if you want to parse error messages
            # smth = stderr_pipe.readline()
        except err:
            # reading failed - something went wrong with process construction
            return

        if len(smth) != 0:
            # smth is read from stderr
            failed = True
            return
        else:
            # the pipe is empty - the process terminated without writing to stderr
            pass
            return

def record():
    "Returns `True` if the process runs without errors and `False` otherwise."
    # command_line = ["ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "warning", "-hide_banner", "-y", "-f", "gdigrab", "-framerate", "30", "-i", "desktop", "output.mkv"]
    command_line = ["ls", "/no/such/file"]
    # for testing: successfull command
    # command_line = ["ls", "/bin/bash"]
    
    command = subprocess.Popen(command_line, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    t = threading.Thread(target=read_stderr, args=(command.stderr,))
    t.start()

    # sleep(5)
    # command.stdin.write('q'.encode('utf-8'))
    command.stdin.flush()
    command.wait()
    
    t.join()
    global failed
    return not failed
    

success = record()
print("Success: ", success)
```

Для тестирования я использовал команды `ls /no/such/file` и `ls /bin/bash`. В первом случае вывод был

```
Success:  False
```

во втором

```
/bin/bash
Success:  True
```

Comment: спасибо, попозже протестирую.

Answer (score 0):

```
command = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = command.communicate()
print(err)
```

Comment: `sleep(5)` куда-то подевался, а автору не нужна бесконечная запись

Comment: @andreymal ну это минимальный код, понятно его надо расширить ;)

Comment: Собственно, суть вопроса в том, как его расширить-то) Даже я не знаю как правильно это сделать в винде

Comment: @andreymal, А какую OC вы используете? Может если вы предоставите код под моё решение для вашей OC, кто-нибудь его переделает